# Selecting ALL text in a PDF file

Tags: pdf

I want to change text colour for a PDF file in Acrobat Adobe DC, but it seems to me that when I do CTRL+A, it only selects alll text in a single page of a PDF. Seeing as I have a PDF with 100 pages, this is quite tedious. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: But Ctrl+A with edit PDF menu works for me. See if all the pages have texts not an image.

Comment: It doesn't work with me. They are text inside (separate) textboxes, but I would think that it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Click on View => Page Display => select "Enable scrolling". 
Try again.

Comment: This works in Acrobat to copy all text on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Way past redemption.

However the OP question was related to their previous question that text (unseen) seemed to be in "Text Boxes". This is a common means to store comments such as may be spoilers in Mark-up /Annotations. Such as can be scripted for an "Answer Sheet".

Here are two such "Text Boxes" that I have ensured are visible. and we can see they are NOT selected along with the page content for copy and paste, but can be selected individually.

[image]

Oddly "Adobe Reader" does include them as output for "Read Aloud" (File Save as Text) and you can export the full plain text including those comments, as seen lower right, it is not very useful as it is designed for Audio Readers.